# How to get list of Discord users using GetUsersAsync?

Tags: c#, discord

```
[Command("ListMembers")]
public async Task ListMembers()
{
     var user = Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync(RequestOptions.Default);
     await ReplyAsync(Convert.ToString(user));
}
```

I tried to use this code to have a bot I am making send a list of all users in a discord server, but all that it does it returns this:

```
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncEnumerableAdapter1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection1[Discord.IGuildUser]]
```

I assume I shouldn't be converting to string, as GetUsersAsync says it returns a function, but I am not sure how to use it. All I really want to do is to use be able to retrieve specific users, the sending of the name is just a way I can see it works.

Comment: An enumerator usually has a property such as `Current` and a method such as `MoveNext`. Each time `MoveNext` returns `true`, you should have a new value in `Current`.

Comment: It looks like `GetUsersAsync` is returning an `IAsyncEnumerable<>`. Read up on how to use them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8

Answer (score 0):

Your bot is returning that text because the variable `user` is dynamically being given the datatype AsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection> due to the return type of GetUsersAsync() method. When you perform a ToString() on an object you will usually get the object definition as the result.

In order to return back a list of each users name, then you will have to loop through each entry in the GetUsersAsync() returned value and grab the name from that.

To do this in one go you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) to go through each entry in the IReadOnlyCollection and retrieve the data you want.

```
// Using await here will mean this returns as a IReadOnlyCollection<IGuildUser> so we don't have to manually deal with asynchronous code.
var guildUsers = await Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync(RequestOptions.Default);

// Using LINQ .Select() to enumerate through each entry and collect the Username property.
// I'm assuming .Username is a property that you can use. Update this to an appropriate property if not the case.
var guildUserNames = guild.Users.Select(user => user.Username);

// Now let's convert the array of strings into a single, comma delimited string
var commaSeperatedGuildUserNames = string.Join(',', guildUserNames);

await ReplyAsync(commaSeperatedGuildUserNames);
```

Comment: This, for the most part, looks like it will work, the only problem is that I am getting an error on everything right of the = sign on the first line of code you wrote, saying:
`'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuildUser>>' Does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IGuildUser>>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)`

Comment: Not too sure why you're getting an error using 'await'. Have you made sure that the function is declared as 'async' and are on a newer version of .NET?

Comment: If that doesn't work, then just go `var guildUsers = Context.Guild.GetUsersAsync(RequestOptions.Default).Result;`. We wont run the code asynchronously, but it can get your code working while you look for a fix for the original problem.

Comment: I was on version 4.7.2 of .Net Framework and updated to 4.8. I am sure that the function (a command in this case), is declared as 'async' along the top. Despite that, it gives the same error. If I substitute in your new code, it gives a similar error. It's identical to the previous error, but rather than saying 'GetAwaiter' as the source of error, it says 'Result'.

Comment: I watched a tutorial when making this code, and they said only to use version 4.7.2. 4.8 seems to work fine, but that's as far as I can update.